# Jplayer playlist demo won't work in IE, but a version implemented on another site does - why?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jplayer, playlist

I'm trying to implement jPlayer (ver 2.1.0) as an audio player with a playlist. I was becoming veeeery frustrated by the fact that the player was working perfectly in every browser except IE8. Typical really. (I'm on XP so I currently can't test IE9, but since that version has much improved HTML5 support I'm guessing it'll behave as in other browsers.)

I assumed that the problem was in my code - I went searching and prompted by various forums and sources checked the swfpath, hanging commas and so on, to no avail.  I decided to check out the [audio playlist demo page](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02/) of the jplayer website using IE8 and to my surprise found that it wasn't working - the playlist wasn't appearing and none of the buttons functioned. I found the same to be true for [the video playlist page](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-video/) as well - no success in IE8. My current solution, therefore, has been to hide the player from all visitors to my site using IE8 and earlier. This is far from ideal, but I assumed the issue to be fundamental to IE and not one that could be resolved by me at least.

However, I found [this version of jplayer](http://augustjohnston.com/mp3/index.htm) via another discussion, and it works without issue in IE8. The playlist appears and everything functions as normal. What gives? What's different in this code than elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer 2.1 requires version 10.3 of the Adobe Flash plug-in, minimum

Comment: Hi Lloyd, cheers for that - I'm not certain that would be the problem, as I was using the same browser (with latest Flash) for both pages...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - I had this problem , I found the solution was to ensure the correct doctype - in my case

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

at the beginning of the document sorted it.
Hope this helps someone!